# May FILE be implemented as a function type in c?

Tags: c

I see the standard only said that FILE is a object type, but what's the object type in c? built-in type, struct, union and emun? Is fuction type a kind of object type? Can FILE * cast to void * always correctly?

Comment: An object type in C is anything that isn't a function type really. So no, it cannot be a function type.

Comment: @SergeBallesta *except* function pointers: the C standard doesn't guarantee it (POSIX however, demands they be convertible to/from `void*` too due to how `dlsym()` works)

Comment: And any pointer to type can safely cast to `void *` and back.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta function pointer not

Comment: @linux40: I meant *pointer to object type*, but you are right I should have said it...

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Thank you, i just want to cast FILE * to void *, but i was not sure if function is a kind of object type before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- what's the object type in c? built-in type, struct, union and emun?

yes, plus some other "intrinsic" types such as `mtx_t` or `atomic_flag`

- Is function type a kind of object type?

no, function types are different, they are those that are declared by designated function declarations.

Functions can be called by using a `f(something)` notation. For object types this is invalid.

- Can FILE * cast to void * always correctly?

yes, pointer to object types (that are not `const` or `volatile`) can always be converted to `void*` and back without loosing anything.